# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as' when doing CAST

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting

I am trying to change the value of the data that comes out of the SQL. Where it usually has the value of 4 in SAL_ClientTypeID, I would like it to say 'Private'. The error I am currently getting is

> "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'as'."

Initially I tried the following

```
   CASE
       WHEN SAL_ClientTypeID = 4 THEN  'Private'
       ELSE SAL_ClientTypeID
   END,
```

but I got this error

> "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Private' to data
>   type int."

```
SELECT SAL_Account_Ref AS 'Account Ref',
       CASE
           WHEN SAL_ClientTypeID = 4 THEN cast (sal_clienttypeID as nvarchar(20)) as 'Private'
           ELSE SAL_ClientTypeID
       END
FROM sales;
```

I expect the value of output where SAL_ClientTypeID = 4 to be 'Private'

Comment: `else cast(SAL_ClientTypeID as nvarchar(20)) `

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SAL_Account_Ref AS 'Account Ref',
       CASE
           WHEN SAL_ClientTypeID = 4 THEN 'Private'
           ELSE cast (sal_clienttypeID as nvarchar(20))
       END
FROM sales;
```

Comment: @BurhanPazar, I'm glad you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix datatypes in a CASE... try

```
SELECT SAL_Account_Ref AS 'Account Ref',
       CASE
           WHEN SAL_ClientTypeID = 4 THEN  'Private'
           ELSE CAST(SAL_ClientTypeID, as nvarchar(20))
       END
FROM sales;
```

Comment: The purpose of `cast` is to mix datatypes. Perhaps you meant that a `case` expression evaluates to a single datatype based on the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your query:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comes from having `as` followed by a string literal, this should be followed by column name:

```
SELECT SAL_Account_Ref AS Account_Ref
```

The second error is because you return two datatypes on the case - string if it equals to 4, int otherwise, you should use casting to make sure it's always the same:

```
SELECT SAL_Account_Ref AS Account_Ref,
       CASE
           WHEN SAL_ClientTypeID = 4 THEN 'Private'
           ELSE cast (sal_clienttypeID as nvarchar(20))
       END
FROM sales;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a datatype priority in tsql. Number types have higher priority than text types. Thus, when your `case` includes both text like 'Private' and number types like SAL_ClientTypeID, the number overrides. When the case of 'Private' comes, tsql tries to convert it to a number and throws the error you see.

If you are OK with having the SAL_ClientTypeID as text, use one of the other answers. Otherwise, you'll have to rethink your specification.